# How it work different matrix of find function

Tags: matlab, find

First, I declared two matrices.

```
a = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8];
b = [2 4 6 8];
```

then, i used to find function.

```
find(a < b)
ans = 
       1
       3
       5
       7
```

My question is how it works? i tried another way like it.

```
a < b
ans = 
    2 x 4 logical array
    
    1  1  1  1
    0  0  0  0
```

So, i can't understand how work find function is work about different matrices.

Comment: `find` with a single output looks for the **linear** index of a matrix where the condition is met. In your case, the linear indeces `[1, 3, 5, 7]` correspond to the elements of the first row.

Comment: @MatteoV 
I don't understand yet.
I tried another matrix

`a = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12]`
`find(a<b)`
`ans =
    1\n
    4\n
    7\n
    10`
Still, idk how compare a to b, and why ans is column vector??

Comment: (1) MATLAB expands `b` to match the size of `a`, it is called [implicit singleton expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/). (2) `find` always returns a column matrix. `find(M)` is the same as `find(M(:))`, that is, first you turn the input into a column vector, then find the indices of the non-zero elements. If you do `[i,j]=find(M)` you will instead get the two indices to each of the non-zero elements of the 2D matrix `M`.